# Criar arquivo a partir do shell

Tags: shell-script

eu estou com um código que criei, e preciso que ele crie um arquivo.txt depois da execução que eu mandei, porém ele não está fazendo.
Segue código para melhor entenderem, agradeço desde já a ajuda.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -a vetor_arquivos #Declara vetor dos arquivos
grep -R package*  ./Javas *.java > teste.txt #gera um arquivo com todos os arquivos encontrados
mapfile vetor_arquivos < ./teste.txt  #recupera arquivo mapiando para um vetor

for i in "${vetor_arquivos[@]}"; do #Percorre o vetor

    echo $i #printa arquivo encontrando

done
echo "FIM"
```

Ele está imprimindo na tela do terminal mas, não cria o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Se vc tá falando dessa linha aqui :

```
grep -R package*  ./Javas *.java > teste.txt
```

Ele deve ter criado o arquivo, mas como vc não colocou o caminho completo ele deve estar em outro lugar ...

É super importante especificar o caminho completo das coisas em bash, acredito que vc deva especificar o caminho completo de onde quer que o arquivo seja criado, ex:

```
/home/user/teste.txt
```

Também recomendo que coloque o caminho completo de onde esta a pasta `Javas`...

Não esqueça que também tem aqui `mapfile vetor_arquivos < /home/user/teste.txt` para alterar

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.